# Combobox selection text using ValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have been struggling with getting an editable WPF ComboBox to show the correct text, when selecting one of the items in the ComboBox.

I'm using a ValueConverter to format the text for each items and this works great in the drop down selection list, but as soon as I select an item in the list, the selected text shows the name of the type, instead of the value of the selected item (As it is shown in the drop down list).

My XAML code looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BananaConverter x:Key="BananaConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=Bananas}" >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BananaConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

And the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow:Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Bananas = new Banana[]
        {
            new Banana("First", "Second"),
            new Banana("1st", "2nd"),
        };

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public struct Banana
    {
        public Banana(string first, string second)
        {
            First = first;
            Second = second;
        }
        public string First;
        public string Second;
    }

    public IList<Banana> Bananas
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

[ValueConversion(typeof(MainWindow.Banana), typeof(string))]
public class BananaConverter    :IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MainWindow.Banana? banana = value as MainWindow.Banana?;
        if(!banana.HasValue)
            return "Meh, that is bad";

        return banana.Value.First+" "+banana.Value.Second;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My ComboBox drop down list looks like this (Which is what I expect):

> First Second
>
> 1st 2nd

But, when selecting the first item on the list, the result will be shown as:

> WPF_Test.MainWindow+Banana

When I expect it to be shown as:

> First Second

I have tried a large number of things, including using a value converter on the SelectedItem / SelectedValue / Text and using a DataTemplate to format the Banana data type, but I still succeding in finding a way to properly format the selected text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change :

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=Bananas}" >
```

by

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" TextSearch.TextPath="TwoParts" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyWindow, Path=Bananas}" >
```

And change Struct:

```
public struct Banana
{
    public Banana(string first, string second)
    {
        First = first;
        Second = second;
    }
    public string First;
    public string Second;

    public string TwoParts 
    { 
        get
        {
            return First + " " + Second;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately changing the source class isn't an option, as it comes from a source I can't modify.

Answer (score 0):

You can style it if you dont want change your data model or if your converter is too complex

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TempCollection}">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Content="{Binding Converter={StaticResource TempConverter}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                                <Border
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ComboBox>
```